# How to delete user in oo php api (using postman testing tool)

Tags: php, mysql, database, crud

I am working on an basic crud API. So far i have a working get function, but want to delete the current users. MY tables are as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` 
(
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_fullname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`user_email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`user_password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`user_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

This is the delete code, how can i delete a user by specific id?

```
} elseif ($this->get_request_method() == "DELETE"){


            $result = $this->db->query("DELETE * From users");


            $result->close();


            // Send the response to the response() function (lives in the parent class) the 200 is the HTTP status code that's returned
            $this->response(json_encode("Deleted", JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), 200);

        } else {

            /*
             * THE METHOD IS NOT ALLOWED
             */

            $this->response(json_encode("Method Not Allowed"), 405);

        }
```

Comment: `WHERE id='$id'` basically.

Comment: could you expand sorry, i have tried the following but no luck

if($this->get_request_method() != "DELETE"){
$this->response('',406);
}
$id = (int)$this->_request['id'];
if($id > 0)
{    
mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = $id");
$success = array('status' => "Success", "msg" => "Successfully one record deleted.");

Comment: There's an answer below. Mine was a very basic example. For more information on the `WHERE` clause, consult https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html

Answer (score 1):

You could send the user_id in the URL string then delete that specific record

```
http://url.com.script.php?user_id=123

// get the user ID and cast to an integer
$user_id = (int) $_GET['user_id'];

// run the query
$result = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id");
```

of course, you'd want to sanitize the `$user_id` against SQL injection in your query, just in case...

Comment: Hello Tim, This is for an API and tested through postman, I have taken your advice and used this, however cannot get the desired result

Comment: You have to specify the user ID, and specifying it will be determined if you're using `$_POST` to submit a form, or `$_GET` and pass it through a link. How are you calling your script?

Comment: The script is being called via postman API testing tool: the link is below.

chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm/index.html

fostvm.fost.plymouth.ac.uk/modules/soft338/sfletcher/users/1

Comment: in your script, do a `print_r($_GET)` to see what the last URL parameter is named. Then reply with it here i.e.; `sfletcher/users/1` 1=the last URL parameter.

Comment: For the record, this `user_id = (int) $_GET['user_id'];` should be `$user_id = (int) $_GET['user_id'];` ;-)

Comment: Anytime Tim ;-) Long time no chat.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, i got a little burned out on the pretentious jerks here. They suck all the joy out of helping people.

Comment: I get the occasional "live ones" every once in a while. That's why I use the comments box ;-) if they can't figure it out from there, then it's not worth it from thereon.

Comment: Plus, those newcomers expect "magical answers" to suddenly appear. I see them coming a mile away. I check their previous questions (if any), then know for sure they have "next to no experience". It always opens up a proverbial "can of worms". I help those who help themselves.

Comment: I smell what you're cooking :)